# Linphone ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - Xcode 10

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode10, linphone

I initially removed library named `lstdc++` because `Xcode` required me to remove and added another library named `libc++` instead.

After that, another error occurs and then i cannot figure it out for 2 days already.

What it shows me error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::_List_node_base::unhook()", referenced from:
  std::list<Linphone::Conference::Participant, 
std::allocator<Linphone::Conference::Participant> 
>::remove(Linphone::Conference::Participant const&) in 
liblinphone.a(conference.cc.o)
"std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)", referenced from:
  Linphone::Conference::addParticipant(_LinphoneCall*) in 
 liblinphone.a(conference.cc.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
  invocation)
```

Do you guys have any ideas about this issue? I have been looking for some another website and it told me to follow this [libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd](https://github.com/Kila2/libstdc-.6.0.9.tbd) but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works for me
-> i removed  libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd  -> clean and delete derived data -> run
please backup your code and try it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I was able to resolve it by copying lstdc++ from old xcode AND setting CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY option in build setting to libstdc++.

Here what you need to copy, assuming both xcode versions are in /Applications and named xcode 10 and xcode 9:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.* /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/

cp /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.* /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/

cp /Applications/Xcode9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libstdc++.* /Applications/Xcode10.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/
```

Dont forget to clear derived data and restart your xcode.